# WPF application as a component of another program

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have Application-A that sends a file over FTP. I designed the application in Expression Blend.

I would like to take the existing Application-A and make it, instead, into a FTP component within a new Application-B with greater functionality.

Application-B would pass a file location into the FTP component. When the file location is verified, the new FTP component would launch/load/display and enable the user to send the file.

How can I implement this functionality with the two applications? How can I include one application as a component of another?

Comment: Is your question regarding how to send the file over FTP or is it about verifying the file and launching your Expression Blend app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can host the window of the other process.
2. You can launch the other program as another process, and send file location by environment variable or command-line argument.
3. You can compile the other program as a dll, delete it's "app", launch its window as a model, or change its window into a container and include it in your new program.

Comment: quickest way is to rip the code out of your first project, copy it into a usercontrol project.